# How to reveal type of material nodes in 2.8

Tags: materials, node-editor, shaders

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out, which types of nodes were used in the creation of a shader/material in the node editor. I did download a Blend file from the web and was curious to analyze the shaders and nodes, but when I open the Node Editor I can only see the custom names of most nodes, and not their "type", which I would need to reconstruct and explore.
For example: I got a [image: Pine Bark Node], which outputs a Factor and has a Texture, Thickness and Indentation. But I cant really figure out, which node this actually is.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It looks like a node group, if you select it and press tab you can get into, ctrl G to group nodes, ctrl alt G to ungroup

Answer (score 3):

I think the question applies even if the nodes are not in a group. I think the question is about how to know which node the user needs to create (for example an IMAGE TEXTURE, or a NORMAL MAP), based on a existing shader setup.

To know a node type, in Blender 2.92, just press N in the SHADER EDITOR, and in the SIDEBAR, the node original name (or the node type) will be there.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a Node Group.
It is not a node by itself - rather a kind of a directory/folder.

It contains a node tree, with different inputs and outputs.
To enter or leave it press <kbd>⇥ Tab</kbd> or the little top right arrow

*Inside of a node group.*
[image]

It is used to organize complex node trees, or sharing node trees across materials.
You can also rename your group, or the nodes inside of it - so it's easier to navigate.

Further reading:
[Node Groups Page in Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/texture_node/types/groups.html)